# Where should I put the html in my angular directives?

Tags: angularjs

When writing a directive I end up writing (sometimes a lot) of html-code in my javascript.

I don't like to have xml in my javascriptfiles. Templating can become pretty complex, most  markup engines will render it in one colour and you have to use ' and +. Is there any good practice to separate the html and the javascript.

Here is a sample of how it can look:

```
angular.module('ballentines', ['ngStorage']).
directive('fineUploader', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {},
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function($scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
            $scope.uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploader({
                debug: true,
                element: element[0],
                request: {
                    endpoint: 'endpoint',
                    accessKey: 'accesskey'
                },
                signature: {
                    endpoint: '/s3/'
                },
                iframeSupport: {
                    localBlankPagePath: '/success.html'
                },
                retry: {
                    enableAuto: true // defaults to false
                },
                text: {
                    uploadButton: '<p>Upload File</p>'
                },
                template:
                    '<div class="qq-uploader">' +
                        '<p class="qq-upload-drop-area">{dragZoneText}</span></p>' +
                        '<div class="qq-upload-button btn btn-info">{uploadButtonText}</div>' +
                        '<span class="qq-drop-processing">{dropProcessingText}</span>' +
                        '<ul class="qq-upload-list" ></ul>' +
                    '</div>',
            });
        }
    };

})
```

Comment: You should push the template into it's own file, then load it via templateURL property.
Save's you a lot of messing with those '+' charachters, too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rather than `template` you could use `templateUrl` and feed it with the addres of a partial html file.

```
angular.module('ballentines', ['ngStorage']).
directive('fineUploader', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {},
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function($scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
            $scope.uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploader({
                debug: true,
                element: element[0],
                request: {
                    endpoint: 'endpoint',
                    accessKey: 'accesskey'
                },
                signature: {
                    endpoint: '/s3/'
                },
                iframeSupport: {
                    localBlankPagePath: '/success.html'
                },
                retry: {
                    enableAuto: true // defaults to false
                },
                text: {
                    uploadButton: '<p>Upload File</p>'
                },
                templateUrl:'partial/your_file.html'
            });
        }
    };

})
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `templateUrl` to specify a location where a html file with the template is kept

[From Doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

> Best Practice: Unless your template is very small, it's typically
>   better to break it apart into its own HTML file and load it with the
>   templateUrl option.

```
angular.module('ballentines', ['ngStorage']).
directive('fineUploader', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {},
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function($scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
            $scope.uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploader({
                debug: true,
                element: element[0],
                request: {
                    endpoint: 'endpoint',
                    accessKey: 'accesskey'
                },
                signature: {
                    endpoint: '/s3/'
                },
                iframeSupport: {
                    localBlankPagePath: '/success.html'
                },
                retry: {
                    enableAuto: true // defaults to false
                },
                text: {
                    uploadButton: '<p>Upload File</p>'
                },
                templateUrl: 'mytemplate.html'
            });
        }
    };

})
```

then in mytemplate.html

```
<div class="qq-uploader"><p class="qq-upload-drop-area">{dragZoneText}</span></p><div class="qq-upload-button btn btn-info">{uploadButtonText}</div><span class="qq-drop-processing">{dropProcessingText}</span><ul class="qq-upload-list" ></ul></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have already stated that it would be easier to put your HTMl into a template and use templateURL to link the code in.

What I would like to add is that you should look into some template services to help make things easier once you start writing test.

I use grunt in most of my angular projects so this is the one I ended up using.

https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-angular-templates